# Connect Two ScrollView’s Together with different Content Offset Values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

To Scroll 2 different scrollView together, Many questions have been already answered regarding using the scrollViewDidScroll Method and passing the content offset of one scrollview to other.

But My Question here is a bit different, Let’s say I have 2 ScrollView A and B both with horizontal scrolling only.

When the view loads ScrollView A has contentOffSet say (x,y) and B scrollview’s content offset : (m,n).

As per my understanding content Offset is the new (x,y) value while scrolling.

Now I can’t pass the content Offset value of A to B here to scroll them together as they loads at different points due to content requirement.I need the exact x points displaced while scrolling in A, then may be pass it to B.

I have also tried getting the velocity from pangesture of A and passing it to B, which doesn’t work smoothly.

How can I achieve a smooth scrolling for both views ?

Comment: Just a question why do you need to make use of 2 different scrollViews? get content in one scrollView, During slow scrolling it may lag a little

Comment: I can't get content in a single scroll view, A is CollectionView and it's scrollview's offset is set to let's say (9000,0) at viewDidLoad.
View B is scroll view and with completely different content with offset at (0,0).
Now when user scrolls A it goes to (9999,0) so now I can't really pass this offset to B, I need to pass 999 x points to B that ways I can add to it's offset's x value.
Basically I am just curious to know if by any way I can get the x points displaced while scrolling like by subtracting previous offset with current one.
I am not able to fetch those exact values.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. But if you want to be updated about when scroll view A changes it's `contentOffset` you can subclass `UIScrollView` and pass the data through a delegate or a closure.

```
class ScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var contentOffsetChanged: ((CGPoint)->())?

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            if let contentOffsetChanged = contentOffsetChanged {
                contentOffsetChanged(contentOffset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

After reading the comment you left me and the one you wrote to iOS Geek, it seems contradictory. There are a few possibilities for how your math would work out so don't take my exact solution as the answer, but more of the design. I think this is the design you're interested in.

```
class Controller: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var scrollViewB: UIScrollView?
    var initialOffset: CGPoint = .zero

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func loadScrollViewB() {
        initialOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        scrollViewB = UIScrollView()
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.scrollView {
            var contentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
            contentOffset.x = initialOffset.x - scrollView.contentOffset.x
            scrollViewB?.contentOffset = contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here, this thing I know how to get updates about change in offset, but let me clear out what I am trying to do.
Let's say I have a ScrollView A, and user scrolls/drags it horizontally.
Initially its content offset is (0,0) and after scroll it goes on to (60,0).
So I want to get x=60 i.e the points displaced on x.
Otherwise yes as mentioned by ios Geek in comment above, I can switch to alternate routes for achieving the same.